# Integral by using substitution (How to proceed?)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Using the substitution $x=a\sin\theta$, or otherwise, find $\int\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$.

My attempt, 
$x=a\sin\theta$

$dx=a\cos (\theta)d\theta$. Then $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin ^2(\theta)}$
The given answer is $-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a^2x}+c$

How to proceed then?

Answer (score 2):

Other possibility:

Use  $x=1/y$, the integral becomes:
$$
I(a)=\int -\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2} \sqrt{a^2-\frac{1}{y^2}}}dy=-\int \frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2y^2-1}}dy=-\frac{1}{a^2}\int \partial_y\left(\sqrt{a^2y^2-1}\right)dy=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2y^2-1}}{a^2}+C
$$

Resubstitute:
$$
I(a)=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{ a^2 x}+C
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using your substition:

$$\int\frac1{x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\;\rightarrow\;\int\frac{a\cos\theta\;d\theta}{a^2\sin^2\theta\cdot a\cos\theta}=-\frac1{a^2}\int\frac{d\theta}{-\sin^2\theta}=-\frac1{a^2}\cot\theta+C$$

Comment: How $\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin ^2(\theta)}$ becomes $a\cos \theta$?

Comment: @Mathxx But... **you** wrote that in your question before you edited it! Anyway, it's simple trigonometry: $$\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{a^2(1-\sin^2\theta)}=a\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}=a \cos\theta$$

Comment: To be fully correct (since we do not know about intervals or sign of $a$) we should add an absolute value around the $a\cos\theta$, so $\sqrt{a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta}=|a\cos\theta|$.

Comment: @mickep You've got a point. +1

Comment: How to proceed then?

Comment: @Mathxx Well, the sign of $\;a\;$ is unimportant, but the one of $\;\cos \theta\;$ is. When you ge to Riiemann Integra (i.e., definite integrals), you will have to separate the integration interval in parts where cosine is poisitve and negative. In this case, I think that pointing out what mickep mentioned is enough.